# Independence is "conversely distributive"

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I am trying to prove or disprove the following:

Given three random variables $X$, $Y$ and $Z$
$$
X\perp Z \text{ and } Y\perp Z \Rightarrow (X,Y)\perp Z 
$$ 
or equivalently
$$
 P(X,Z) = P(X)P(Z) \text{ and } P(Y,Z)=P(Y)P(Z) \Rightarrow P(X,Y,Z) = P(X,Y)P(Z).
$$

The closest I've got is by using another theorem which I haven't been able to prove/disprove either:
$$
\begin{split}
P(X,Y,Z) &= P(X|Y,Z)P(Y,Z) \\
&=P(X|Y,Z)P(Y)P(Z) \\
&=P(X|Y)P(Y)P(Z)\\
&=P(X,Y)P(Z)
\end{split}
$$
where I used the unproven theorem 
$$
X\perp Z \Rightarrow P(X|Y,Z) = P(X|Y).
$$

Thanks!

Comment: Not true. Counterexample given many times on this site and elsewhere: $(X,Y)$ uniform on $\{-1,1\}^2$, $Z=XY$.

Comment: Hmm... and "the unproven theorem $X\perp Z \Rightarrow P(X|Y,Z) = P(X|Y)$" is actually not a theorem but a wrong statement.

Comment: See e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2402922/pairwise-independent-random-variables-that-arent-jointly-independent/2402927

Comment: Great, thank you! Thanks also for helping me correct my vocabulary.